# How to remedy the web.config error that results when a server is unavailable where a web service is located?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, web-config

I have a simple ASP.Net C# application that gets some information from a web service then displays it in an iframe in a web page. The application runs fine most of the time, unless for some reason the server that hosts the web service is down or unavailable. Please refer to the web.config snip and the line with the web service url. The error will highlight the **<endpoint address=** line when the web service server is unavailable. I've tried various things but don't know the correct way to handle this issue.  Thank you for your help.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
  ::: ::: :::
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WebServiceSoap" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://locaionOfWebService/WebService1.asmx"  
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SampleWebServiceSoap"
                contract="ServiceReference1.WebServiceSoap" name="WebServiceSoap" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Code; basicHttpBinding is being used.

```
var webservice = new OffSiteWebService.WSSoapClient("WSSoap1");    
var data = webservice.GetWebServiceInfo(parm1, parm2);
```

Comment: Please add an example of the code that you are using to call the service. This will help with the answer that you get back.

Comment: I suspect the code that calls the web service will need to change along with the binding that is used. But the current code that actually makes the call works fine, **unless** the remote server is down/unavailable. When the remote server is down the `web.config` file itself that gets the error, not the code calling the webservice.  Also the first thing I tried was to make a `get request` to the server and only call the web-service if the response code is 200 OK. This is when I realize it's the web.config file itself that gets the error because it can't configure the web-service endpoint.

Comment: NOTE: basicHttpBinding is being used.  
`var webservice = new OffSiteWebService.WSSoapClient("WSSoap1");  
 var data = webservice.GetWebServiceInfo(parm1, parm2);`

Comment: Please add the additional information into your question, so all your steps can be followed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As luck would have it the webservice causing the issue was down today while working on this issue (It's actually one of many similar webservices with the same issue).  In production we get the **Server error in Application** error page that tells you to turn customErrors ON, even though the `web.config` for the application **did have customErrors ON and 4 different error pages defined.**
Error page displayed:
[image]

What I failed to realize was that the proxy service that our application interacts with **also has it's own** `web.config` and the proxy service did not contain any error handling in it's code or `web.cofig`.  Just simply adding a try/catch in the code that calls the web service is handling the issue.

```
try {
    var webservice = new OffSiteWebService.WSSoapClient("WSSoap1");
    var data = webservice.GetWebServiceInfo(parm1, parm2);
    ::: ::: :::
    }
catch {
    return default values
    ::: ::: :::
    }
```

I may also add some additional error handling code but at the moment the above solution is working.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this in a couple of ways.

1. When you make the call to the web service take a look at the the StatusCode of your response. This should be 200 for OK. If the service is not available you might have received something like a 404 (Not Found). If you post your service calling code I can provide a more specific answer.
2. You can impelment a retry framework, that will keep trying your service call based on a policy that you set. Take a look at Polly as a good place to start - https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly

**NOTE**: StatusCodes are HTTP specific, not just related to ASP.NET. see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status

Comment: Thanks for your response.  That's actually the first thing I tried.  I made a get request to the server and only call the web-service if the response code is 200 OK. _This is when I realize it's the **web.config** file itself that gets the error._   Note: basicHttpBinding is being used.

Comment: The web.config file does not run code. It is a static file used to hold variable data that is used by your application. 

That said can you describe further what you mean by "its the web.config file that gets the error". What symptoms, or error message are you seeing? Can you provide a screenshot of the error?